# Query syntax on a large inner-joined select query linked to a control giving runtime 3071 error message

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting Runtime error message 3071 on the following query stating that the query is too complex. I have created queries in the past which have seemed more complex than this one. I would like to understand what generates this message:

```
sql_get = "SELECT tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso, tblValueChain02.IDMicroProcesso02, tblValueChain03.ID, tblDependencies01.ID AS DependencyID, tblValueChain02.MicroProcesso02, tblValueChain01.MacroProcess, tblValueChain01.TeamLead, tblValueChain01.LastOrganisationDate, tblValueChain01.TempiIndeterminati, tblValueChain01.TempiDeterminati, tblValueChain01.Interinali, tblValueChain01.PartTime, tblValueChain01.DailyMinutesAverage AS Minutes01, tblValueChain01.DailyMinutesHigh AS Minutes01H, tblValueChain01.DailyMinutesLow AS Minutes01L, tblValueChain02.MicroProcesso02, " & _
"tblValueChain02.DailyMinutesAverage AS Minutes02, tblValueChain02.DailyMinutesHigh AS Minutes02H, tblValueChain02.DailyMinutesLow AS Minutes02L, tblValueChain03.MicroProcess, tblValueChain03.MinutesPerDay AS Minutes03, tblValueChain03.MinutesPerDayHigh AS Minutes03H, tblValueChain03.MinutesPerDayLow AS Minutes03L, tblDependencies01.FlowDescription, tblDependencies01.FlowType, tblTeamsDepartments.Department, tblTeams.Team, tblDependencies01.Precision, " & _
"tblDependencies01.ServiceDelivery , tblDependencies01.RiskReduction, tblDependencies01.CapacityCreation, tblDependencies01.TargetCapacityCreation, tblDependencies01.Feasibility, tblDependencies01.Timeframe, tblDependencies01.Priority, tblDependencies01.Note, tblDependencies01.RedundantControls, tblDependencies01.RedundantControlsNotes, tblDependencies01.RedundantControlsPotSolution, tblDependencies01.RedundantControlsNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.RedundantControlsPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.RolesAndResponsibilities, tblDependencies01.RolesAndResponsibilitiesNotes, " & _
"tblDependencies01.RolesAndResponsibilitiesPotSolution , tblDependencies01.RolesResponNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.RolesRespPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.SubstandardSvcs, tblDependencies01.SubstandardSvcsNotes, tblDependencies01.SubStandardSvcsPotSolution, tblDependencies01.SubStandardSvcsNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.SubStandardSvcsPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.KnowledgeGaps, tblDependencies01.KnowledgeGapsNotes, tblDependencies01.KnowledgeGap, " & _
"PotSolution , tblDependencies01.KnowledgeGapsNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.KnowledgeGapsPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveOversight, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveOversightNotes, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveOversightPotSolution, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveOversightNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveOversightPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.UpstreamErrors, tblDependencies01.UpstreamErrorsNotes, tblDependencies01.UpstreamErrorsPotSolution, tblDependencies01.UpstreamErrorsNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.UpstreamErrorsPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.DefectsRework, " & _
"tblDependencies01.DefectsReworkNotes , tblDependencies01.DefectsReworkPotSolution, tblDependencies01.DefectsReworkNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.DefectsReworkPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.OverProduction, tblDependencies01.OverproductionNotes, tblDependencies01.OverproductionPotSolution, tblDependencies01.OverproductionNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.OverproductionPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.MotionTransport, " & _
"tblDependencies01.MotionTransportNotes , tblDependencies01.MotionTransportPotSolution, tblDependencies01.MotionNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.MotionSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.DowntimeWaiting, tblDependencies01.DowntimeWaitingNotes, tblDependencies01.DowntimeWaitingPotSolution, tblDependencies01.WaitDowntimeNotesSymbol, tblDependencies01.WaitDowntimeSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveHandoffs, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveHandoffNotes, tblDependencies01.ExcessiveHandoffPotSolution, " & _
"tblDependencies01.ExcessiveHandoffsSymbol , tblDependencies01.ExcessiveHandoffsPotSolSymbol, tblDependencies01.RCSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.RCSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.RCCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.RCOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.RRSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.RRSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.RRCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.RROperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.SSSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.SSSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.SSCorporatePolicyBreach, " & _
"tblDependencies01.SSOperatingModelDiscrepancy , tblDependencies01.KGSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.KGSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.KGCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.KGOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.EOSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.EOSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.EOCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.EOOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.UESLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.UESLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.UECorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.UEOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.DefSLABreachInternal, " & _
"tblDependencies01.DefSLABreachExternal , tblDependencies01.DefCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.DefOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.OPSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.OPSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.OPCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.OPOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.EHSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.EHSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.EHCorporatePolicyBreach, " & _
"tblDependencies01.EHOperatingModelDiscrepancy , tblDependencies01.DTSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.DTSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.DTCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.DTOperatingModelDiscrepancy, tblDependencies01.ECSLABreachInternal, tblDependencies01.ECSLABreachExternal, tblDependencies01.ECCorporatePolicyBreach, tblDependencies01.ECOperatingModelDiscrepancy " & _
"FROM (tblTeamsDepartments INNER JOIN tblTeams ON tblTeamsDepartments.ID = tblTeams.Department) INNER JOIN (tblValueChain01 INNER JOIN ((tblValueChain03 INNER JOIN tblValueChain02 ON tblValueChain03.IDMacroProcess = tblValueChain02.IDMicroProcesso02) INNER JOIN tblDependencies01 ON tblValueChain03.ID = tblDependencies01.IDSubProcess) ON tblValueChain01.IDMacroProcesso = tblValueChain02.IDMacroProcesso01) ON tblTeams.ID = tblDependencies01.Group WHERE [tblDependencies01].[ID]= '" & ID & "'"
Form_frmValueChainDynamic01.Form.RecordSource = sql_get
```

Comment: If you remove the `WHERE` clause, does Access still complain that it is too complex?

Answer (score 1):

Possible typo:

```
...
INNER JOIN tblValueChain02 ON tblValueChain03.IDMacroProcess = tblValueChain02.IDMicroProcesso02)`
...
```

...perhaps should be `IDMacroProcesso` (missing "o" at the end of this field)?

Is `[tblDependencies01].[ID]` a number field? If so, then in your `WHERE` clause you've used single quotes denoting you're expecting to match a string; so this:

```
WHERE [tblDependencies01].[ID]= '" & ID & "'"
```

...should be written like this, if `ID` is a number:

```
WHERE [tblDependencies01].[ID]=" & ID
```

You've referred to most fields in your `SELECT` clause using the `tableName.fieldName` convention except for `PotSolution` (this may not be an issue, but it's good to be consistent!)

Some more things to try if the above doesn't work: http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html#QueryTooComplex